# is it possible to pass form contents via ajax call to server?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to validate a form by making ajax calls from my web page.  I'm just wondering if there's a way to pass all contents of form in one shot (using jquery, let's say), or if i have to pass each element in form as separate values?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
$('form').serialize()
```